# Hiding an element in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I'm trying to hide an element in my ClearCase view. I've set the following line in my config spec:

```
element /path/to/some/element -none
```

Further down in my config spec, there is an include to another config spec (which in turn includes other config specs and so on - a complete mess, but I can't change this). I'm pretty sure there is another line in there setting this element to a tagged version. When I do `ct ls` on the file I see:

```
/path/to/some/element@@/main/1        Rule: SOME_TAG
```

Is the `-none` option to `element` overridable by a tag? If so, how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm a config spec wouldn't operate well through a symbolic link.
See [config spec man page](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm)

> There is no VOB symbolic link scope.
>   A VOB symbolic link is cataloged (listed) in one or more versions of a directory element

A vob symbolic link [adds some issue with the config spec](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_tshoot_relo.htm) (seen for instance after relocating elements)

Even without talking about *Vob* symlink, [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM32034) mentions that ClearCase config spec without an unrelated wildcard or unrelated recursive rule will not resolve the end point of a symlink.

Comment: I think mine was a regular UNIX symbolic link, but the same discussion applies.

Comment: Yes, regular symlink is addressed in the last link of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What dawned on my was that the path to the element contained a link to another VOB. After I changed the path to the absolute path of the other VOB, it worked:

```
element /var/vob/other_vob/vob/path/to/some/element -none
```

Apparently config spec settings don't apply through links.